# Generate ean13 barcode and save it to png

Tags: php, prestashop, ean-13

I am using `Kody kreskowe - EAN-13` by Jacek Kowalski (http://jacekk.info) to generate EAN13 barcode and save it to image file. I would like generate barcode dynamically during the ordering process in Prestashop. Save that image on server and put it in new_order.html email template.

There is whole code: https://jacekk.info/skrypty/ean13.phps

I modified it lightly by change `$_GET['kod']` to `$kod_in` and put `$kod_in = 1234567891011` at start of file and `imagepng($i, $new_filename);` at the end

Everything works well (I see generated barcode and script create new image file and save it on server) when I enter directly to file ean13.php or if I run that code (directly in web browser):

```
$kod_in = 1234567891011;
include (dirname(__FILE__)."/ean13.php");
```

But when I try include the above code into order process, exactly in mailalerts.php, it does not display barcode and generate blank (white) image file. I think it has something to do with the fact that the generated barcode is not displayed on the screen, and then is saved.

Please help modify the code to generate the images even though they are not displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the script replace this:

```
header('Content-type: image/gif');
imagegif($i);
```

With this:

```
$imageLocation = "where/you/want/to/save/your/file";
imagegif($i, $imageLocation);
```

Here is [`imagegif` Documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagegif.php)

---

You can use this library as a Class this way:

```
<?php
/***************************************************
 *             Kody kreskowe - EAN-13              *
 ***************************************************
 * Ostatnia modyfikacja: 01.11.2012                *
 * Autor: Jacek Kowalski (http://jacekk.info)      *
 *                                                 *
 * Strona WWW: http://jacekk.info/scripts/barcodes *
 *                                                 *
 * Utwór rozprowadzany na licencji                 *
 * http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/  *
 ***************************************************/

/* Kodowanie znaków UTF-8 */

class BarCode {

    public $kol = array(
        '0' => array('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
        '1' => array('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
        '2' => array('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B'),
        '3' => array('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A'),
        '4' => array('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'),
        '5' => array('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'),
        '6' => array('A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A'),
        '7' => array('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'),
        '8' => array('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'),
        '9' => array('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A')
    );

    public $code = array(
        'start' => '101',
        'lewa' => array(
            'A' => array(
                '0' => '0001101',
                '1' => '0011001',
                '2' => '0010011',
                '3' => '0111101',
                '4' => '0100011',
                '5' => '0110001',
                '6' => '0101111',
                '7' => '0111011',
                '8' => '0110111',
                '9' => '0001011'
            ),
            'B' => array(
                '0' => '0100111',
                '1' => '0110011',
                '2' => '0011011',
                '3' => '0100001',
                '4' => '0011101',
                '5' => '0111001',
                '6' => '0000101',
                '7' => '0010001',
                '8' => '0001001',
                '9' => '0010111'
            )
        ),
        'srodek' => '01010',
        'prawa' => array(
            '0' => '1110010',
            '1' => '1100110',
            '2' => '1101100',
            '3' => '1000010',
            '4' => '1011100',
            '5' => '1001110',
            '6' => '1010000',
            '7' => '1000100',
            '8' => '1001000',
            '9' => '1110100'
        ),
        'stop' => '101'
    );

    public $b;

    public function __construct($barcode) {

        $len = strlen($barcode);
        if(trim($barcode, '0123456789')!='' OR ($len!=12 AND $len!=13)) {
            echo 'Znaki inne niż cyfry lub błędna długość ('.$len.')';
            die();
        }

        $kod = str_split(substr($barcode, 0, 12));
        $now = 1;
        $sum = 0;
        foreach($kod as $val) {
            if($now==1) {
                $sum += $val;
                $now = 3;
            }
            else
            {
                $sum += $val*3;
                $now = 1;
            }
        }
        $sum = 10-($sum%10);
        if($sum==10) $sum = 0;

        if($len==12) {
            $barcode .= $sum;
        }
        elseif(substr($barcode, -1)!=$sum) {
            echo 'Błędna suma kontrolna '.$sum;
            die();
        }

        unset($len, $kod, $now, $sum);

        $sys = substr($barcode, 0, 1);
        $lewa = substr($barcode, 1, 6);
        $prawa = substr($barcode, 7);

        $i = imagecreate(95, 40);
        $w = imagecolorallocate($i, 255, 255, 255);
        $this->b = imagecolorallocate($i, 0, 0, 0);

        $this->print_code($this->code['start'].$this->gen_binary($lewa, 0, $sys).$this->code['srodek'].$this->gen_binary($prawa, 1, $sys).$this->code['stop'], $i);

        imagegif($i, 'test.gif');
    }


    public function gen_binary($kod, $strona, $sys) {
        $kod = str_split($kod);
        $ret = '';
        if($strona==0) {
            foreach($kod as $key => $val) {
                $ret .= $this->code['lewa'][$this->kol[$sys][$key]][$val];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($kod as $val) {
                $ret .= $this->code['prawa'][$val];
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    public function print_code($kod, $img) {
        $now = 0;
        $kod = str_split($kod);
        foreach($kod as $val) {
            if($val==1) {
                imageline($img, $now, 0, $now, 40, $this->b);
                $now++;
            }
            elseif($val==0) {
                $now++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to include it once at the top of your file before your class declaration:

```
 include_once('path/to/BarCode.php');
```

Now instead of including the script to generate an image you'll have to create a new `BarCode` Object.

```
 new BarCode('9780486425573');
```

Tested and working on my Prestashop 1.6.

Comment: You didn't read carefully. I have `imagepng($i, $new_filename);` at the end. Because I want png.

Comment: Sorry I misread it. Don't you have any errors in apache log files? Did you removed the `header([...])` before `imagegif([...])` call?

Comment: I don't have any error logs. Yep, I removed it. I'm fighting with it since yesterday. As I said: when I open directly `ean13.php` with hard-coded `$kod_in` - it works. But when I try include `ean13.php` in mailalerts.php, script generate blank image, as if `$kod_in` was not sent, but it was, I checked it.

I put `ean13.php` to cron, and it works, so this is not, how I thought, the problem with displaying the image in browser.